# SSRS report - show value only if "pk" is present and if not then blank

Tags: ssrs-2012

I would like some help with a ssrs report.

When "PK" is present in column 2 i want to display the value in column 1 and if "PK" is no present in column 2 then to display nothing.

i have the below expression i just need the false to be blank.

=iif(Fields!ProdeCode.Value = "PK",Fields!LastMaterialCost.Value,False)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to replace False with Nothing? or ""?

```
=iif(Fields!ProdeCode.Value = "PK",Fields!LastMaterialCost.Value,Nothing)
```